# bcftool merge of 5K samples makes ID a large string

Tags: vcf, bcftools, merge, command-line

I am using bcftools to merge 5000+ vcf files  using this command

```
bcftools merge -l list_of_vcfs.txt
```

I am getting the following error

```
 Warning: The row size is too big for FORMAT/PL at chr1:23899810, requires 12204615120 bytes, skipping.
The REF prefixes differ: C vs N (1,1)
Failed to merge alleles at chr1:53128382 in <sample>.vcf.gz
```

Any help on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @bioinfo_comp and welcome to the site. It's a good sign when the bot message is acted upon, particularly as quickly as you have done. Hope you stick around.